# var_dump says I have an object, but php error says I am trying to get the value of a non-object

Tags: php, object, foreach

I can't understand why it says I am trying to get the property of a non-object when my `var_dump` says I have an object.  Below is the output of my `var_dump`.  It clearly says:

```
  ["chooseImagesTypes"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1620 (2) {
    ["chooseImagesTypes0"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1619 (3) {
```

So it is saying both are objects.  I tried adding `(object)` before my code to ensure it's an object not an array but that didn't work.  Here's the full `var_dump`, plus the error message, and my code.

**var_dump**

```
object(stdClass)#1622 (4) {
  ["images0"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1617 (2) {
    ["mediaManagerImagesSubform"]=>
    object(stdClass)#1618 (3) {
      ["maxOrMinSize"]=>
      string(9) "min-width"
      ["mediaQuerySize"]=>
      string(3) "959"
      ["chooseImagesTypes"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1620 (2) {
        ["chooseImagesTypes0"]=>
        object(stdClass)#1619 (3) {
          ["mediaManagerOrUrl"]=>
          string(1) "1"
          ["mediaManagerImage"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["externalUrlImage"]=>
          string(44) "homepage/joomla-london-hero-image--1200.webp"
        }
      }
    }
```

**My Code**

```
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($images);
    echo "</pre>";

    echo '<picture>';
    foreach ($images as $image) {
            foreach ($image->mediaManagerImagesSubform as $imageSubform) {
                foreach ((object)$imageSubform->chooseImagesTypes as $imageType) {
                    if(!empty($imageType[$i]->$externalUrlImage)) {$imageURL = $imageType[$i]->$externalUrlImage;} 
                    else {$imageURL = $imageType->$mediaManagerImage;}
                    echo '<source ';
                    echo 'media="(' . $imageSubform->maxOrMinSize . ':' . $imageSubform->mediaQuerySize . 'px)" ';                              
                    echo 'srcset="' . $imageURL . '" ';
                    echo 'type="image/' . substr($imageURL, strrpos($imageURL, '.') + 1) . '"';     
                }                   
            }
        echo '>';
    }
    echo '<img src="' . $defaultImage . '"' . ' alt="' . $altText . '">';
    echo "</picture>";  
  }
```

**The Error Message**

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'chooseImagesTypes' of non-object in /x~/default.php on line 54
```

Why is it telling me it is not an object?
Is there a better way to do nested foreach statements?

Things I tried.

Casting it as an object using (object).  Also without that.

```
(object)$imageSubform->chooseImagesTypes
```

Using iterative notation like this (with and without).  I tried it in various places but to no avail.

```
$imageType[$i]
```

What confuses me is that the other parts seem to work using the same code and I can't see the difference.  Usually in instances like this I find out it's an array, but `var_dump` and `print_r` both refer to it as an object and casting using `(object)` doesn't fix it (although if it's an array I'll just use `['arrayItem']`).

Comment: Is that the *entire* `var_dump`?

Comment: yeah I also think SOME elements of the vardump have said property but some don't

Comment: Please reduce this to the required [mcve]. I'm sure you'll find the error on the way yourself. Also, learn how to use a debugger in order to step through code.

Comment: I'm going to try this.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Step_through_code just leaving it here in case anyone stumbles across this and needs the same advice.  I'll update the link if it's incorrect after I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use "`$mediaManagerImagesSubform`" as an array while it is an object;

Try something like:

```
foreach ($image->mediaManagerImagesSubform->chooseImagesTypes as $imageType)
{
  if (!empty($imageType[$i]->$externalUrlImage)) {
    $imageURL = $imageType[$i]->$externalUrlImage;
  } else {
    $imageURL = $imageType->$mediaManagerImage;
  }
  echo '<source ';
  echo 'media="(' . $imageSubform->maxOrMinSize . ':' . $imageSubform->mediaQuerySize . 'px)" ';
  echo 'srcset="' . $imageURL . '" ';
  echo 'type="image/' . substr($imageURL, strrpos($imageURL, '.') + 1) . '"';
}
```

At last, remove the unnecessary loop (I mean the `foreach ($image->mediaManagerImagesSubform as $imageSubform)` part)